# How to edit file 'description' label and help text

Tags: 8, hooks, files

I want to edit the file upload description label and the help sentence underneath it:

[image]

I tried the below code:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $context) {
  if (isset($element['#field_name'] == 'field_file_description') {
      // Add process callback to change field description.
      $element['#process'][] = 'chg_desc';
    }
  }
}

function chg_desc($element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form) {
  $element['#description'] = t('Trying to edit desc help');
  return $element;
}
```

It does not have any impact on the field label and help text. How can they be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the machine name of your file field is `field_file_description`.

According to [FileWidget.php#L414](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.3.x/core/modules/file/src/Plugin/Field/FieldWidget/FileWidget.php#L414), the description is it's own element in the form, so instead of `$element['#description']` it should be `$element['description']['#description']`. I just tested that and it works.

Here is a working code sample:

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form_alter(&$element, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $context) {
  if (!array_key_exists('#field_name', $element)) {
    return;
  }
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_file_description') {
    // Add process callback to change field description.
    $element['#process'][] = 'mymodule_process_field_file_description';
  }
}

function mymodule_process_field_file_description($element, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form) {
  $element['description']['#title'] = t('Help!!!');
  $element['description']['#description'] = t('Trying to edit desc help');
  return $element;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so so much for this help. the machine name for my field was field_attachment. changing that, worked out the magic for me!